# Starscream on iOS and WatchOS - Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, watchkit, starscream

im trying to use Starscream both on iOS and WatchOS with Cocoapods.

here's my podfile:

```
inhibit_all_warnings!

def all_pods
    pod 'Starscream', '~>3.0.5'
end

target ‘ProjTest’ do
  platform :ios, '10.0'
  use_frameworks!
  all_pods
end

target 'ProjTestTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
end

target 'ProjTestUITests' do
   inherit! :search_paths
end

target 'ProjTestWatch' do
  platform :watchos, '5.0'
  all_pods
end
```

I have a class, SocketManager, that I use on the app already, I just want to use that same class on the watchApp Target, but the only error im getting is : `No such module 'Starscream'`  on the import line.

The most weird for me, is if im go look the `Framework Search paths`, and  `Header Search Paths` on the Watch Target, they're both empty. But if I try to do the same as the iOS app target. and put an `$(inherited)`, they inherit the libs from the iOS App.

Comment: Have you tried 'use_frameworks!' for watchos target?

add, pod install, clean and build

Comment: Yes, already tried use_frameworks!, still same error